# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near " ": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, save

I'm having a problem while adding records in SQLite.

**This is the Error**:

```
09-18 17:47:47.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.capstone.pinoygoodies/com.capstone.pinoygoodies.GroceryView}:
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near " ":
   syntax error:
   CREATE TABLE tblItem 
                 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                  grocery_item TEXT NOT NULL,
                  grocery_qty TEXT NOT NULL
```

**My CREATE TABLE**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
KEY_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
KEY_ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
KEY_QTY + " TEXT NOT NULL ");
```

Whenever I hit the add button, this error is being triggered.

Comment: Could post the code where you are creating the table?

Comment: you are missing the  ) at the end. You need to include it too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.execSQL("
    CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
    KEY_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    KEY_ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_QTY + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
);
```

There are easy to mix up. You just need the close parenthesis.

*Suggestion:*

```
String createStatement = 
    String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                   AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT NOT NULL, 
                   %s TEXT NOT NULL);",
                        DATABASE_TABLE,
                        KEY_ITEMID,
                        KEY_ITEM,
                        KEY_QTY);
```

If you construct your table like this, I personally think it makes the statement much easier to read for things like SQL Syntax and then you can bind the data later.

Answer (score 3):

Append ")" at the end of Create Table Query.

Answer (score 1):

error is throw by create table, not get data.

check your create table sql statement

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the right parenthesis of the Create Table Syntax, correct it as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE tblItem 
                 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                  grocery_item TEXT NOT NULL,
                  grocery_qty TEXT NOT NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
KEY_ITEMID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
KEY_ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
KEY_QTY + " TEXT NOT NULL )");
```

You need to add ")" at last in your create table.

Insert Query

```
    String qty = "QTY";
    String item = "ITEM";
    String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" (qty, item) VALUES('"+ qty +"','"+ item + "')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: This works fine with me but I'm having new problem now.

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tblItem has no column named qty: , while compiling: INSERT INTO tblItem(qty, item) VALUES(?, ?);

I have declared the column for qty.