# sqlite throws exception on creation of table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating a simple table but on executing the table it throws the error like this:

```
    10-06 09:15:28.606: E/AndroidRuntime(595): 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near  "item": error: 
    create table item (_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    item_id text not null,  
    item_name text not null);
```

My dbhelper class is:--

```
<code>
```

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL);",
                "item","_id", "item_id", "item_name");
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "applicationdata";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Method is called during creation of the database
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);
}

// Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
// e.g. if you increase the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DbHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item");
    onCreate(database);
}
```

}

```
</code>
```

please help me.

Comment: post your create table query code.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488718/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-near-syntax-error

Comment: see my answer its working in my case..

Answer (score 1):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists item(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "item_id TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "item_name TEXT NOT NULL)");
```

Comment: i also tried it... its not working.. i saw the create statement in debugging it is perfect but cant figure out whats hppening

Comment: try to uninstall your app, and run again, if you create table that already exists (it exists after first run) without `if not exists` your statement will fail.

Comment: fixed misprint in answer, please retry

Comment: @KailashDabhi now any issue regarding this? if not then accept answer and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "item" is not in the [keyword list](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite, but that's when I've seen an error like that come up before...

Try changing your table name to something else and see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some spaces problem (before AUTOINCREMENT) and syntax:

```
private static final String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL);",
            "item","_id", "item_id", "item_name");
```

or just:

```
private static final String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL);",
            "item","_id", "item_id", "item_name");
```

as AUTOINCREMENT keyword is not necessary along with "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" in [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)